# Bash or Python: How to download a single specified file from Github?

Tags: python, git, bash, github, download

I need to write a script which periodically downloads a specific file from my Github account. I've seen [this Github page](https://help.github.com/articles/downloading-files-from-the-command-line) which seems to be what I am looking for, but I have not been able to get it to work. Perhaps this is because I do not really understand what the "user" field is (as opposed to "username"). If anybody had any success with this method, could you please provide an example? Also, if you used another method, could you please let me know? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the filetype.  For non-binaries, you can get the url of the file by clicking on the "raw" button next to "edit" when you have the file open in github.  Then, you can just just use `curl` or `wget` to download it.

Here is a picture to make things clear:

[image]

Then copy the url:

[image]

Comment: It's a python script. I know that I can view the "raw" of the file, but I am not sure of two things:

1. How to get the RAW url?
2. How to deal with credentials when downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is synced, I'd write a bash script that went something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# file: ./getFromGit
# cd into git-synced directory and update the file
cd /directory/path/
git checkout origin/branch /path/to/file/in/dirStructure
```

Then

```
$ chmod u+x ./getFromGit
$ cp getFromGit /usr/local/bin # or wherever your executables like git are
```

Now from any directory you like, you can call getFromGit and it will get the file you 
want.

See [this tutorial from Jason Rudolph](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/) for more info on checking out a single file from a given branch with git.

If it's not synced, I agree with @jh314: just use wget

Answer (score 0):

This should work (untested, but should give you an idea):

```
import time
import subprocess
import sys
import shlex

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmd = ("curl -L" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "wget")
    url = ......
    cmd += " {0} -o {1}".format(url, url.split("/")[-1])
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    (stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()

    if stderr:
        raise Exception(stderr)

    time.sleep(...)

    # Call another instance of this script
    subprocess.Popen(['python', sys.argv[0]])
```

It will call the script again after the time has elapsed, and exit.  As long as the command finishes without an error, it will keep calling itself again.