# Read a CSV file with PyGithub

Tags: python, csv, github, pygithub

I just want to read a CSV file from a Github repo with PyGithub.

```
from github import Github
g = Github(token)

repo = g.get_repo("user/example")
contents = repo.get_contents("h.csv")

with open(contents, "r") as f1:
    last_line = f1.readlines()[-1]
last_id_csv = last_line.split(",")[0]
```

But I don't know how to manage [ContentFile()](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/ContentFile.html) type to have the CSV file.

CSV file content is something like:

```
id,number,text
1,1234,blabla
2,2345,blabla
3,4534,blabla
4,3423,blabla
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try looking at [Is there a way to import csv file from github automatically to my jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609760/is-there-a-way-to-import-csv-file-from-github-automatically-to-my-jupyter-notebo).

Comment: I have decoded the content, but it is still not recognised as CSV. If I try a csv.reader, it doesn't print the entire row.

Code until now:

`from github import Github
g = Github(token)

repo = g.get_repo("user/example")
contents = repo.get_contents("h.csv")
inputFile = contents.decoded_content.decode('utf-8')
    
tocsv = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=',')
for row in tocsv:
    print(row)`